# How to make jquery scrolling effect work on multiple element/classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a very light script for multiple classes `class"demo"` that can work on my `onScrollDown` responsive animation.

I don't really understand about writing arrays. but, I believe that if I use `document.getElementsByClassName("demo")[i]` , `i < 0` and some `function(i)` I can implement it for individual classes. Because I use `getBoundingClientRect()` instead of fixed `value`.

So, how can I write it correctly using `i` as arrays?

Thank you..

---

Here is my working script :

```
<script>
var e = document.getElementById("demo");
var rect = e.getBoundingClientRect();
var x = rect.top;
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > x-300) {
        $('#demo').addClass('animate');
    } else {
        $('#demo').removeClass('animate');
    }
});
</script>
```

*work only for a single element.

---

Here is what I'm trying to do, that not working yet

```
<script>
var e = document.getElementsClassName("test")[i];
var rect = e.getBoundingClientRect();
var x = rect.top;
var i;
for (i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
  $(window).bind('scroll', function (i) {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > x-300) {
          $e.addClass('animate');
      } else {
          $e.removeClass('animate');
      }
  });
}
</script>
```

---

CSS :

```
<style>
.test {
    background:#345;
    color:#FFF;
    height:2em;
    padding:.5em;
    top:50px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    width:100%;
}
.animate {
    width: 60px;
}
</style>
```

---

HTML

```
<div style="color: red; margin-bottom: 400px;">(Top!)</div>
<div class="test" id="demo">Menu</div>
<div class="test" id="demo">Menu</div>
<div class="test" id="demo">Menu</div>
<div style="color: red; margin-top: 400px;">(Bottom!)</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your full code?

Comment: There you go,, I use a simple code just to try if the script is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I've achieved what you're trying to do. Here are the changes I made:

1. Used the JQuery `each` function. This will loop all of the `demo` elements every time a scroll is detected. There are other ways of looping the elements but because you've already imported JQuery we may as well use it's functions.
2. Changed `#demo` to `.demo`. In other words, I've changed `id` to `class`. `id` should only be used when working with elements that are completely unique. In this case, there are multiple `demo`s so we use `class` instead.

Final code (as you scroll each element will turn red showing that the `animate` class has been added:

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {

  $('.demo').each(function(i, obj) {
    var rect = obj.getBoundingClientRect();
    var x = rect.top;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > x - 300) {
      $(obj).addClass('animate');
    } else {
      $(obj).removeClass('animate');
    }
  });
  
});
```

```css
.body {
  height: 200vh;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.demo {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.demo.animate {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="body">
  <div class="demo"></div>
  <div class="demo"></div>
  <div class="demo"></div>
  <div class="demo"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you explain me what does the `i` and `obj` inside `function(i, obj)` stood for

Comment: @RedFrog Yeah of course :) So the `i` and `obj` are the variables used to get the current loop element when inside the `each`. The `obj` is the current loop object (The value can also be accessed through the `this` keyword) and the `i` is the current loop objects index. You can find more information about it here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/#entry-longdesc

Answer (score 0):

There are few notes in regards to your code:

- In jQuery you can get elements offset by using `.offset()` function.
- you should not use the same id more than once per page.
- `.bind()` has been deprecated since jQuery 3.0. Use `.on()` instead.
- To toggle class you can use `.toggleClass(className, state)`. State is used to determine if you want to remove or add the class.

See this example:

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  jQuery(".test").each(function() {
    let isTop = $(window).scrollTop() > jQuery(this).offset().top - 300;
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('animate', isTop);
  });
});
```

```css
.test {
  background: #345;
  color: #FFF;
  height: 2em;
  padding: .5em;
  top: 50px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.animate {
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="color: red; margin-bottom: 400px;">(Top!)</div>
<div class="test">Menu</div>
<div class="test">Menu</div>
<div class="test">Menu</div>
<div style="color: red; margin-top: 400px;">(Bottom!)</div>
```

Comment: The script is perfectly working as I expected. Thank you man.. Maybe my last question is, is there any reason why you prefer to use `let` instead of `var`? thank you..

Comment: `let` and `const` are the new variable definition keywords. They replace `var`. I use them mainly for scope but there are number of reasons to use them. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var